# Changes to params in grails only seen in controller not in views

Tags: model-view-controller, grails, parameters

Part of my UrlMappings looks like this:

```
"/$lang"(controller: "main", action: "front") {
        constraints {
            lang inList: ['hr', 'sl', 'si']
        }
    }
```

Because I want to set `lang` to 'sl' if it is 'si', I created following filter:

```
def filters = {
    all(controller: '*', action: '*') {
        before = {
            if(params.lang == 'si') {
                params.lang = 'sl'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem: `params.lang` inside controller gets the wanted value ('sl'), but in views, `params.lang` gets resolved to the original value ('si'). What would you suggest to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use redirects. I did this way:

```
def filters = {
        pages(controller: 'pages', action: 'home|services|projects|project_details|contact_us|career|about_us|downloadCaseStudy') {
            before = {
                if (params.lang) {
                    if (!(params.lang in grailsApplication.config.i18nFields.locales)) {
                        session."$SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME" = null
                        params.remove('lang')
                        response.sendError(404)
                        return
                    }
                    if (params.lang == grailsApplication.config.defaultLocale) {
                        RCU.getLocaleResolver(request).setLocale(request, response, new Locale(params.lang))
                        params.remove('lang')
                        chain(controller: "pages", action: params.action, model:chainModel?:[:],params: params)
                        return false
                    }
                } else {
                    String langCode = RCU.getLocale(request).getLanguage()
                    if (!(langCode in grailsApplication.config.i18nFields.locales)) {
                        params.lang = grailsApplication.config.defaultLocale
                        return
                    } else if (langCode != grailsApplication.config.defaultLocale) {
                        params.lang = langCode
                        chain(controller: params.controller, action: params.action, model:chainModel?:[:], params: params)
                    }
                    return true
                }
            }
            after = { Map model ->

            }
            afterView = { Exception e ->

            }
        }
```

A little explanation: I build urls like **/ru/about_us**. 
1.If lang not in list - 404.
 
2.if lang = grailsApplication.config.defaultLocale show instead of **/en/about_us** just **/about_us**.
3. if no lang param provided - resolve from request.